# No loader-wizard in ioncube installer?

Tags: centos, centos-6, installer

Trying to install IonCube on Centos 6, and well whenever I download the ioncube, there is no installer like the tutorials say there are.

I am following the digital ocean tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ioncube-loader

I am using the 64bit version located at the bottom of the page.

I checked my server to ensure it was not just me typing the URL incorrectly and there is no actual loader-wizard file for the installer.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the loader-wizard from [their website](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php) and put that in your webroot, the wizard is not included in the normal tarball.

Comment: Its the same file. http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz

Comment: I found it. Nevermind, trying to get it to work now, thanks again.